# Making an outline border for a pointy button in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a button in CSS like the image below. I have tried in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udJ9L/1/) and I can get a solid shape but not one with a outline border?

[image: pointy button]

jsfiddle code:

```
            <div class="point-btn"></div>

            .point-btn
            {
                width: 148px;
                height: 34px;
                background: #0a187e;
                position: relative;
                -moz-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
                -webkit-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
                border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
                margin-left:50px;
            }
            .point-btn:before
            {
                content:"";
                position: absolute;
                left: 100%;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 17px solid transparent;
                border-left: 14px solid #0a187e;
                border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a child element and overlay triangle as well.

You need to tweak up your markup a bit by adding `span` as a child element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/udJ9L/9/)

Here, what I did is, am cloning your triangle with different dimensions and overlay on your blue triangle, that will give your triangle a border effect, and next, I set `absolute` `span` element which is again positioned `absolute` to the parent element. If you want you can also use `margin` to set the element right and get rid of the `/absolute` position.

```css
.point-btn {
  width: 148px;
  height: 34px;
  background: #0a187e;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.point-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 148px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #0a187e;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
}
.point-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 147px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 4px;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
.point-btn span {
  width: 142px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="point-btn"><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right it ain't pretty but both answers do what I asked for.

Answer (score 4):

Not too pretty- but you should get a decent starting point, simply use another pseudo element overlain on your existing triangle shape:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udJ9L/6/)

```css
.point-btn {
  width: 148px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 2px solid #0a187e;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.point-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0px;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
}
.point-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  top: -4px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #0a187e;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="point-btn"></div>
```